# how to use xauth to run graphical application via other user on linux

Tags: linux, sudo, x11, xauth

My regular user account is, let's say, user1. I created separate user2 for some x application that i would like to run while being logged into x as user1 but in a way that will prevent it from read/write access to user1 data. I thought that i could use xauth and sudo/su to user2 from user1 to run this application. How do i do this? I'm not sure how to configure xauth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found something that works great for me on KDE

```
kdesu -u username /path/to/program
```

Comment: On debian part of [`kde-cli-tools`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=kde-cli-tools), and not in `$PATH` but in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/kdesu` (obviously depending on architecture).

Answer (score 44):

To use xauth **selectively,** as user1 run:

```
xauth list|grep `uname -n`
```

This prints the hexkey authorization entries for you . You *could* have different displays associated with those hosts as well.

As user2 set your display (assuming default case):

```
DISPLAY=:0; export DISPLAY
```

Then run:

```
xauth add $DISPLAY . hexkey
```

Note the dot after the $DISPLAY and before the hexkey.

When access is no longer needed, as user2 you can run:

```
xauth remove $DISPLAY
```

Comment: Problem 1: user2 has no `.Xauthority` file in user2's home directory. Problem 2:  Somehow and for some reason I dont' understand, after `su`, XAUTHORITY holds the filepath to user1's. But that file is not readable by user2.

Comment: Seems, you forgot

`unset XAUTHORITY`

under user2

Comment: is the `hexkey` in the `xauth add` command the same as from `xauth list` or do I have to create a random new one?

Comment: bonanza: it is the the one output from xauth list.

Comment: Another way to do this is would be something like... "xauth extract - $DISPLAY | sudo -iu steam xauth merge -". In this case I have XAUTHORITY set in .profile, so the 'sudo -i' gets that set right.

Answer (score 17):

I put in my `.zshrc` a line with `export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority` and now I am able to execute `sudo -E xcommand`. After a lot of googling, for me this was the easiest way.

Comment: Note that this procedure would not normally require you to use `sudo -E` (and using `-E` is disabled on most default installs) because normally the default `sudoers` configuration would allow the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable to be passed to sudo.

Comment: @Guss It doesn't _require_ `-E`. It can be set as a variable that can be passed, and either Red Hat or Debian suggests it.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - that's what I said :-)

Comment: @Guss Oh, sorry. I somehow inverted every sentence you wrote. :-)

Comment: Still didn't work for me, on Mac OS X with zsh

Answer (score 13):

First: Don't use `xhost +`, it's rather insecure (blanket allow/deny).

Rather use the X-Cookie mechanism:

```
su user2
cp /home/user1/.Xauthority /home/user2/.Xauthority 
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Alternatively, if you have `sux` installed, use that (see ehempel's answer).

In both cases user2 will use the secret cookie in .Xauthority to authorize to the X server, and no one else will have access to it.

Notes:

- Depending on your file permissions, you might have to copy .Xauthority in some other way.
- Instead of copying `.Xauthority`, you can also use `xauth` to extract and copy the authorization key (see Randall's answer). If you have multiple keys in the `.Xauthority` file this is more selective; otherwise it is a matter of taste.

Comment: This is just manually copying the xauth cookies via root access. This is no different from using xauth as Randall explains in the (current) top answer, except it copies every cookie that 'xauth list' would show. So this is less secure than the top xauth answer which would only add the cookies you pick.

Comment: @JohnEikenberry: True, thanks for pointing this out. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming debian or ubuntu (should be similar on Red Hat / SUSE).

```
sudo apt-get install sux
sux user -c 'command'
```

Comment: +1 good answer, no point in reinventing the wheel. Incidentally, sux mostly does what my answer above suggests. It's more powerful and easier to use of course.

Comment: You may note, that  'sux'  indeed is a *simple* shell script, too..

Comment: `sux` is unmaintained (and removed from Debian/Ubuntu's repositories): https://packages.qa.debian.org/s/sux/news/20140101T172633Z.html

Comment: E: Package 'sux' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 8):

As root:

```
xhost local:yourusername
```

Where yourusername is your user name :)

Then do su as your user
    `xclock` should work if it's installed

Answer (score 7):

This will fix the problem for all users:

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/profile.d/xauth.sh
#!/sbin/bash
export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Some other options:

- `xauth +` (unsecure) (doesn't work on recent versions of `xauth`)
- `ssh -X user2@localhost` (ugly, but might be simpler to get to work than direct authentication)

Comment: `ssh -X` is a very simple and elegant solution, not depending on any deprecated/unmaintained gtk/kde stuff (which require installing more binaries with SUID bit...).

Comment: xauth: (argv):1:  unknown command "+"

Comment: @MonaJalal yeah, I haven't used `xauth` in ages, it seems that it has changed significantly. Updated the answer to note that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This way made in suse/opensuse :
http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7003743

Simply modifying the /etc/pam.d/su, adding the option (bold) :

> session  optional       pam_xauth.so    **systemuser=1**

Then you can switch with su without - :

> su user2

and run the app graphically.

Answer (score -2):

For GNOME (and without any desktop environment really, I use it with icewm only) `gksu`:

```
gksu -u username program
```

Comment: "gksu has been deprecated for years": https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=867236

Comment: @Stefan note that this Debian bug is about premise that **elevating** privileges for *whole program* is bad idea, and that the program should instead be modified to just execute minimal helpers with elevated privileges instead (using PolicyKit). This question (and my answer) is about **reducing** privileges, which is another thing altogether and in fact good idea (for example, for random browsing I have shortcut that execute firefox under some less privileged account that my default one, so any exploit there can't touch my data - and gksu(8) is quite fine for that)

Comment: All that is fine, but using a deprecated and unmaintained SUID binary is just wrong.  This answer might have been useful in the past, but isn't anymore.